# Run python in command line in Microsoft Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Code with its Python support on Windows 7.

Now I can open an .py file and run it from menu Debug > Start Debugging. Is it possible to run it in command line?

Comment: python <file.py> usually runs it in command prompt? What do you mean by "Is it possible to run it in command line?"

Comment: thx! that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python  usually runs it in command prompt. Please let me if you need any more details or help